# Does giving a bounty make a significant change?

Tags: support, bounty

I'm a new user on MSE, and there's a question which had been asked about a week ago. It got 4 up-votes and (till now) has no answers, and not even a useful discussion or something. The question is quite interesting (at least to me), and I don't mind giving it a bounty of 100 - 300.

My question is: Does giving a bounty make a significant jump in the attention the question is getting from users? I have never seen a question with a bounty or given a bounty to a question; so I know no much further than the site (help section) can offer.

Comment: "I have never seen a question with a bounty" Here are all the questions with a current bounty: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured

Comment: In this particular case, the question might also get a few more views due to ["meta effect"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).  (Some users who see your post on meta might be curious and go to your profile to see on which question you put a bounty.) Just for the possibility of later comparison: The question has 86 views now.

Comment: This older discussion is somewhat related: [Is bounty really guaranteeing more exposure?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/is-bounty-really-guaranteeing-more-exposure)

Comment: I've had success with bounties; four of the questions I've bountied received answers (though only three received answers during the bounty period, the other one did soon after). The only other bounty I posted made it to the first page of "unanswered questions" from all the attention it got.

Comment: Another related post which provides some statistics: [How effective are bounties?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20155)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had mixed results offering bounties on my own questions. There are certain cases where it definitely helps:

1. The question requires a long/involved answer. People ordinarily discouraged from answering by the amount of effort involved will be more inclined to write something up if there is a bounty. For instance, here are a few questions I answered that I wouldn't have if there hadn't been a bounty offered:
   [Linear ODE and Fourier Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076033/linear-ode-and-fourier-series/1081642#1081642), [covariant and contravariant components and change of basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068862/covariant-and-contravariant-components-and-change-of-basis/1072903#1072903), [Understanding the Laplace operator conceptually](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811901/understanding-the-laplace-operator-conceptually/818799#818799)
2. The question is one that should be easy for a subject-matter expert, but it somehow "slipped through the cracks" and is now far from the front page.

On the other hand, if a question is already very popular, but has no answer simply because it is hard, adding a bounty won't necessarily increase the chance of getting an answer (but might get people to write out in full their current progress and thoughts about the question).